# Read configuration files in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need to read a configuration file (XML or properties file) within an xquery file that is on my local file system i.e. I don't want to put that configuration file in marklogic database. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this and avoid using eval by calling [xdmp:document-get()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3adocument-get). This will read in a file and have it available in memory. If the file has a .xml extension, it will be read as XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file in as a string as long as it is UTF-8 encoded by using `xdmp:filesystem-file` you can then turn it into XML by calling `xdmp:unquote`

```
xdmp:unquote(xdmp:filesystem-file("c:/config.xml"))
```